# Rewrite logical formula to one with only '$\to$' and '$\neg$'?

Tags: propositional-calculus

How can I write:

$A \to B ∧ B \to A $

as a statement with only '$\to$' and '$\neg$' ?

Comment: What is $\hat{}$?

Comment: @JohnGriffin presumably logical and $\land$ `\land`

Comment: @JohnGriffin I edited my answes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:

> $\lnot (P \to Q) \equiv (P \land \lnot Q)$

and thus:

> $\lnot (P \to \lnot Q) \equiv (P \land Q)$.

Thus, we have to rewite the "and" in $(A \to B) \land (B \to A)$ to get:

> > $\lnot ((A \to B) \to \lnot (B \to A))$

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{array}{cl}
& [A \implies B] \land [B \implies A] \\
=& [A \implies B] \land \neg \neg[B \implies A] \\
=& \neg([A \implies B] \implies \neg[B \implies A]) \\
\end{array}$$

Alternatively:

$$\begin{array}{cl}
& [A \implies B] \land [B \implies A] \\
=& [A \land B] \lor [\neg A \land \neg B] \\
=& \neg[\neg A \lor \neg B] \lor [\neg A \land \neg B] \\
=& [\neg A \lor \neg B] \implies [\neg A \land \neg B] \\
=& [A \implies \neg B] \implies \neg [\neg A \implies B] \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA right, corrected.